# Ни убавить, ни прибавить: не или ни?

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

"Ни убавить, ни прибавить" — правильно написано, или тут все-таки должна быть частица НЕ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, союз *"ни... ни"*  вполне правильно употреблен.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь, конечно, "ни ..., ни ...". В смысле нельзя "ни прибавить, ни убавить".
Если не ошибаюсь, здесь это "ни ..., ни..." с противопоставлением трактуется как союз, что для "не ..., не ..." с подобным же противопоставлением совершенно невозможно.

Кстати, я совсем не уверен в необходимости запятой. Скажем "ни дать ни взять" запятой не требует. Вопрос в том, насколько тесным считается подобное смысловое единство. Ефремова даёт без запятой, [тут](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/278031/%D0%BD%D0%B8), в источниках встречается различное написание.

*Что касается пожелания найти осмысленный контекст, требующий "не ..., не ..." то сдаюсь*.

По большому счету я просто не вижу формальных причин напрочь отвегнуть такую возможность (сравните: "Умом россию не понять"), но из вариантов более чем с одним "не" на ум приходит только однородные ("Не сорить, не шуметь!" - да и то с большой оговоркой), но никак не противопоставления.

Comment: А вариант вроде "Не ввозить - потерять [рынок]." ? Т.е. конструкция вроде "инфинитив тире инфинитив"? Возможно как часть бОльшего предложения...

Comment: Возможно, конечно, но это не наш случай. Противопоставления нет.

Comment: А противопоставление не обязательно должно быть. См. [корпус][1]

 [1]:http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E5&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=inf&sem2=&sem-mod4=sem&sem-mod4=sem2&flags2=bdash&m4=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=%ED%E5&gramm3=&sem3=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags3=adash&m3=&parent4=0&level4=0&min4=1&max4=1&lex4=&gramm4=inf&sem4=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags4=&m2=

Comment: *Есть многое на свете, друг Горацио* ©ИхнееВсё
Только наш случай - с противопоставлением. Уберите его - и спорить будет не о чем.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще написание возможно разное. Смотря какой смысл Вы вкладываете в выражение и в каком контексте оно употреблено. Думаю, что можно высосать из пальца примеры, когда будет грамотно в аналогичном выражении написать "НЕ". Но лучше пускай этим займутся более профессиональные знатоки русского, вроде [@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus).

Comment: Вот тут вы ошиблись. Я не профессиональный знаток, а самый что ни на есть дилетент. Мне и ошибться не зазорно. ))))

Answer (score 0):

Полностью это выражение должно звучать так: **нельзя ни убавить, ни прибавить**. Первое слово - *нельзя* - это отрицание, а два последующих *ни* - перечисления. Но в разговорной речи *нельзя* нередко опускают. Поэтому и возникает недоумение: вроде бы речь идёт об отрицании, а применяются частицы *ни*.